# How to get the end of a url in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have an urlconf like this:

```
url(r'^homepage/?(?:.json)?', home),
```

And inside a view, I would like to get the end of the url. I thought something like this could be work:

```
def home(request):
    if request.url.endswith('.json')
        return json_homepage() 
    else:
        return render(request,'other.html')
```

Comment: Could you show an example url?

Comment: Escape the dot in regex: `?:\.json`

Comment: It seems to me like a `GET` parameter. Why dont you just check for that ?

Comment: Indeed, you could use a `GET` parameter or `Accept` header

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, could you provide more info about it?

Comment: @RamiroTomato `.` has a special meaning in regex, it means any character. To use a `.`, you need to escape it.

Comment: @karthikr thanks for your answer. I am not really sure if can solve this using GET because I am not sending any attribute in my url `url(r'^homepage/type=json$', home)` so I can't get any attribute (offset) in my view, I am probably wrong, thanks for the help

Comment: @kroolik, please look at my comment above, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this matching the `request.path_info`

## urls.py

```
url(r'^homepage/?(?:\.json)?', home),
```

## views.py

```
if request.path_info.endswith("json"): 
        return home_json_render()
    else:  
        return render(request, 'frontpage.html', params)
```